# Is ROS Kinect Broken?

Tags: ros, kinect, rosdep

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to follow this tutorial to begin playing with the ROS: http://wiki.ros.org/kinetic/Installation/Ubuntu
but when I do:

rosClient@rosclient-VirtualBox: -$ sudo rosdep init

I get the error:

sudo: rosdep: command not found

maybe am missing something, but do you have any idea what it is??

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/257513/is-ros-kinect-broken?/) by [ΦXocę 웃 Пepeúpa ツ](https://answers.ros.org/users/29728/%CF%86xoc%C4%99-%EC%9B%83-%D0%BFepe%C3%BApa-%E3%83%84/) on ROS Answers with karma: 424 on 2017-03-21

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-03-21**:
Could you please tell us which steps you already completed, and what the output was? It looks like you just haven't installed `rosdep`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Have you tried installing rosdep? Depending on your system the process will vary, check out this link:

http://wiki.ros.org/rosdep#Installing_rosdep

---

Originally posted by [corcorant](https://answers.ros.org/users/29721/corcorant/) with karma: 67 on 2017-03-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1